# Find the distribution of a variable Mj that is part of the chi-squared test random variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test, gamma-distribution

Given the chi-squared test statistic:
$$X^2 = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{(N_j - np_j)^2}{np_j}$$,

And given that the random variable $M_j$ is the number of the $X_i$'s that would fall in the $jth$ interval $[a_{j-1},a_j)$

And given the knowledge that the fitted distribution is in the true one (test is accepted), what is the distribution of $M_j$, and what is its mean?

I understand that the mean would probably be the expected value of the distribution, but I am a bit lost as to how to find the distribution of $M_j$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+distribution or https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multinomial+chi

Comment: Could you please explain briefly the relationship of the binomial distribution to my question? @Whuber

Comment: It follows from the very definition: the Binomial gives the probabilities of counts of the number of occurrences of independent events, such as that $X_i\in[a_{j-1},a_j)$.